# Cyberduck CLI - How to prevent duck asking for authorization when uploading to dropbox

Tags: file-upload, command-line-interface, dropbox-api, cyberduck

I've been experimenting with using Duck CLI to upload files to Dropbox in Windows 10 64-bit.  If I submit a request like:

```
call duck --assumeyes --username abcd --password 1234 --upload "dropbox:/Test Folder" "Test.txt"
```

then it prompts me for the OAuth2 token and a browser tab appears with the authorization code.  I supply this and the upload starts.  All good.  I want to bypass this and use a code that I have generated without the prompt.  I tried:

```
call duck --assumeyes --password <generated key> --upload "dropbox:/Test Folder" "Test.txt"
```

but I still get the prompt and browser tab.  I want the whole upload to proceed with no prompts.  What am I missing?

As a matter of interest, this works as required (with no prompt being issued):

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload ^
  --header "Authorization: Bearer <generated key>" ^
  --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"<DestinationFolder>\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}" ^
  --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" ^
  --data-binary "@<filename>"
```

but the upload speed is only around 1.4Mb/s.  Using Duck it is 11 Mb/s, so eight times faster!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use your email address registered with Google as the `username` parameter. This way the OAuth tokens are found in the login keychain (macOS) or credential manager (Windows).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll try that, but does it explain why I was able to get it to work with curl?